# How to add URL access date to MLA or APA

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style, mla-style

I'm currently using the `mla-good.bst` file for natbib (available as [mla-good.bst.zip](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/images/mla-good.bst.zip)), but I suppose I don't really care if I use APA or MLA, so I may switch later. The problem I am having is that I can't figure out a way to add URL access dates to the bibliography. I would like to add notes to the sources in the bibliography that state the date an online material was retrieved.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any good way to do this. I've seen methods of doing this using MLA and APA formats for biblatex, but none for natbib.

Perhaps I should consider switching to biblatex, but I'm still fuzzy on the differences (advantages/disadvantages) of using biblatex versus natbib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a diff between mla-good.bst and one that enables the "urldate" field.

```
76a77
>     urldate
365c366,371
<     { "\newline\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * write$ newline$ }
---
>     { "\newline\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * write$ newline$ 
>       urldate empty$
>         { skip$ }
>         { "(accessed on " urldate * ")" * write$ newline$ }
>       if$
>     }
```

(thanks Herbert).

Answer (score 2):

http://texnik.dante.de/misc/

there is a mla-goodURL, which knows the field "urldate",
which should be printed if not empty.

Herbert

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Unfortunately, the bst file didn't work as it was, but I've posted the diff for a modified one that does work.