# Add access date to custom bibliography style created with makebst

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, jabref, custom-bib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add “Retrieved”, “Last accessed” or similar information to authoryear in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51079/add-retrieved-last-accessed-or-similar-information-to-authoryear-in-biblate)

I use [JabRef 2.8b2](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) to organize my bibliography references. I used the `latex makebst` command to create a [custom bibliography style](http://pastebin.com/MT3JwDmF) (uploaded to pastebin.com). The custom style produces the following output.

[image: Example reference with my custom style]

However, I would like to add the **access date** to the URL like [masson asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-url-access-date-to-mla-or-apa). I imagine that the style could read the date from the `timestamp` field of the corresponding `*.bib` file. Here is the plain section from the `*.bib` file for the aformentioned example output.

```
@MISC{obama-opengov,
  author = {Barack Obama},
  title = {Transparency and Open Government},
  howpublished = {Website},
  month = {January},
  year = {2009},
  note = {Verified via archive.org},
  timestamp = {2012.03.28},
  url = {http://www.whitehouse.gov/the_press_office/TransparencyandOpenGovernment/}
}
```

**Question:**
How can I add something like `Last accessed at 12-04-04` to the style? Did I miss a question in `makebst` to customize it?

I am not insisting on my bib style if you can recommend another with a similar output. The optimal output would look something like this:

```
[5] Barack Obama: Transparency and Open Government. Website (January 2009). 
    URL: http://www.whitehouse.gov/the_press_office/TransparencyandOpenGovernment/. 
    Verified via archive.org. Last accessed: 2012-04-04.
```

**Further unsucessful attempts:**

I tried to use the [mla-good.bst](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/images/mla-good.bst.zip) and [mla-goodURL.bst](http://texnik.dante.de/misc/mla-goodURL.bst) linked in [massons' question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7327/how-to-add-url-access-date-to-mla-or-apa). I also tried to manually modify them as suggested. However, the date does not print although I added values to the `urldate` field via JabRef. I also tried to replace the fieldname with `timestamp` which did not work either.

Second, I tried [natdin.bst](http://blog.stefan-macke.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/natdin.bst) by [Stefan Macke](http://blog.stefan-macke.com/2006/07/08/din-konformes-literaturverzeichnis-mit-latex/) who uses the `lastchecked` variable for the same purpose. Same result.

After all, I cannot print any date. Further, I cannot see a `lastchecked` field in JabRef. My version of JabRef writes the current date at which I add the entry to the database automatically to field `timestamp`. Therefore, I would prefer to use this field.

Comment: you note that "masson" has asked before; in that case, he was using a bst that was generally available.  it would be easy enough to provide you with general information about how to do this job, but without access to your .bst it's not possible to produce (reliable) "detailed instructions" (would general instructions be useful for you?)

Comment: @wasteofspace I linked my .bst in the beginning of my post.

Comment: @JJD: Is biblatex an option?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Sure. If I can produce the desired output with it.

Comment: @JJD: A small example is given here: tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51079/add-retrieved-last-accessed-or-similar-information-to-authoryear-in-biblate/51082#51082

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thank you. I trying to integrate *biblatex* in my project. Still have some difficulties to add the settings to the *ClassicThesis* project.

Comment: @JJD: Can we close (delete  this question?

Comment: The alleged duplicate is about biblatex, this question seems to be about makebst+bibtex.