# Add "Retrieved", "Last accessed" or similar information to authoryear in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

When citing online resources my university's regulation stipulates that we have to add information on when we accessed the specific website. This can for example be of the form "Retrieved: April 7, 2012".

When using the following simple setup for `biblatex`, is there a field in `@online` or so that allows me to have this printed automatically in the bibliography?

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Comment: You need `urldate`.

Comment: I specified `urldate` but it is ommitted in the bibliography.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Nevermind, works now.

Comment: I had the same problem as @Ingo, thus the  `urldate` was omitted in the bibliography, it was fixed by deleting all the aux files and recompiling.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As I recommend in the comment you need the field urldate. Here an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{ctan,
  label       = {CTAN},
  title       = {CTAN},
  subtitle    = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
  date        = {2006},
  url         = {http://www.ctan.org},
  urldate     = {2012-04-07},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {Retrieved},
}

\begin{document}
Text \cite{ctan}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I also changed `urlseen` to your required string: "Retrieved".

If you want to format `urldate` you can use the following options of `biblatex`:

```
urldate=comp,dateabbrev=false
```

The result will be: *April 7*

The result is:
[image]

Comment: @Ingo In case you use [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) to manage your literature: it automatically sets an insert date to the **timestamp** field for a new entry. Luckily, the target field can be changed to **urldate** in the program's preferences. The date format, however, does **not** accept the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. It always puts `YYYY.MM.DD` and I cannot tell if this works with @MarcoDaniel's solution!?

Comment: I had the same question, and this has been very helpful. However, when I add the urldate=comp,dateabbrev=false options, the "Retrieved" phrase is gone from the citation.. Any ideas?