# How can I set the urlseen label of biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, urls

I'd like to set the default *visited on <date>* to *accessed on <date>* (as per my teacher's specifications). I believe I need to change the `urlseen` label to accomplish this.

Is changing the `urlseen` label the way to go, and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: related question: [Add “Retrieved”, “Last accessed” or similar information to authoryear in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51079/4012)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that you can change the localization keys as described in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/3039):

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen = {accessed on},
}
```

See also the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) under `4.9.2.15 Labels`.