# Reverse order of fields "note" and "url" for entry types "electronic" and "article" (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, urls

I use biblatex for the table of contents with:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, autocite=footnote, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

I have several entries with fields `url` and `note`. (e.g. the types `electronic` (a.k.a. alias type `online`) or type `article` contain an `url` field). In the PDF output the `note` field always comes before the `url`, however I would like to have it the other way around, that is, the `url` first followed by `note`.

For example:

```
@ELECTRONIC{Lorey2008,
  author = {Isabell Lorey},
  year = {2008},
  title = {Kritik und Kategorie},
  note = {Last retrieval at May 21, 2012.},
  url = {http://eipcp.net/transversal/0806/lorey/de}
}
```

Prints in PDF as:

> Lorey, Isabell (2008). Kritik und Kategorie. Last retrieval at May 21,
>   2012. URL: http://eipcp.net/transversal/0806/lorey/de.

However I want it to be:

> Lorey, Isabell (2008). Kritik und Kategorie. URL:
>   http://eipcp.net/transversal/0806/lorey/de. Last retrieval at May 21,
>   2012.

Comment: Would the `addendum` field be okay for you? If not, do you really want the `url` and `note` field reversed only for `online` and `article`?

Comment: I forgot: *Do not use* the `note` field for last retrieved dates, just whack the date into the `urldate` field. In your case: `@ELECTRONIC{Lorey2008,
  author = {Isabell Lorey},
  year = {2008},
  title = {Kritik und Kategorie},
  urldate = {2012-05-12},
  url = {http://eipcp.net/transversal/0806/lorey/de}
}`

Comment: What's `addendum` (I do not see this in JabRef)? Actually, I would always have the `url` before `note`, because I use `note` for the "Last retrieval at ..." part, but maybe there is also a better solution than using the `note` field for this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JabRef, sorry. For `addendum` have a look at [page 14 of the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). Looking at the [`biblatex` documentation (p. 22)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) you should really rather use the `urldate` field as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `urldate` now. However, I also needed to do some style customization, which was easy following the recommendations from 
[Add "Retrieved", "Last accessed" or similar information to authoryear in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51079/add-retrieved-last-accessed-or-similar-information-to-authoryear-in-biblate) and [Two questions on biblatex: remove parentheses on urldate, and change "url" label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51194/two-questions-on-biblatex-remove-parentheses-on-urldate-and-change-url-label)

Thanks to @moewe!